# How to find whether image is blocked in Outlook recipients

Tags: email, outlook, google-analytics

Is there a way to check whether the Outlook recipients are receiving emails with block image security settings? (Perhaps using Google Analytics?)

I need to track how many of them are blocking and whom they are so I can send appropriate emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to track this sort of thing. The only way to track ANYTHING in emails is from pixel requests and if images are blocked, you never get them.